# Gtk* backend requires pygtk to be installed

Tags: python, matplotlib, gtk, pygtk

From within a virtual environment, trying to load a script which uses `matplotlib`'s `GTKAgg` backend, I fail with the following traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/user/.virtualenvs/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/pyplot.py", line 97, in <module>
    _backend_mod, new_figure_manager, draw_if_interactive, _show = pylab_setup()
  File "/home/user/.virtualenvs/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/__init__.py", line 25, in pylab_setup
    globals(),locals(),[backend_name])
  File "/home/user/.virtualenvs/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_gtkagg.py", line 10, in <module>
    from matplotlib.backends.backend_gtk import gtk, FigureManagerGTK, FigureCanvasGTK,\
  File "/home/user/.virtualenvs/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_gtk.py", line 16, in <module>
    raise ImportError("Gtk* backend requires pygtk to be installed.")
ImportError: Gtk* backend requires pygtk to be installed.
```

The code which I ran in order to produce that `ImportError` is as follows:

```
import matplotlib as mpl
mpl.use('GTKAgg')
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

When running the very same code after deactivating my virtual environment, everything goes well.

I assumed this may be due to version differences; indeed, such differences exist on my machine. However, the version in the virtual environment is **newer** (1.2.0 versus 1.1.1rc), so I am not expecting less support.

In case it is not clear: my question is how to allow importing `pyplot` with `GTKAgg` backend on a new version of `matplotlib`, or at least an attempt to understand the reasons for this import failure.

Comment: did you let your virtualenv see system packages?

Comment: I am not sure about that. How can I verify that? However, my first guess is that yes, it can see.

Comment: and as a final note, both version 1.1 and 1.2 of mpl are rather old.

Comment: Check if that solution works for you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42481911/amazon-emr-cluster-matplotlib-error

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You probably created your virtual evn by something like:

```
 $ virtualenv ~/.virtualenvs/my_env
```

by default this can see none of your system-installed packages (including pygtk) so when you try to run mpl it rightly complains that you do not have pygtk installed because (with in the context of the virtualenv) you do not.

You can either build and install pygtk within your virtualenv or you can use

```
$ virtualenv --system-site-packages ~/.virtualenvs/my_env
```

([doc](http://www.virtualenv.org/en/latest/virtualenv.html#the-system-site-packages-option)) which will make your virtualenv inherit from your global packages.

Comment: Just blow it away and make a new one.

Comment: It'll take me hours. I have so many packages there, and so many of them are not easy to install.

Comment: Most packages (at least in the scientific stack) install with `python setup.py install`.  If you don't need specific versions of stuff, you can use the system-level packaged installations which will save you a lot of time.

Comment: This suggestion worked well except I had to use "pip install --ignore-installed matplotlib ipython[notebook]" in order to avoid writing into the system paths.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if you're on Ubuntu, but to solve this I had to install matplotlib from source to get this to work. The key instructions (from http://www.pyimagesearch.com/2015/08/24/resolved-matplotlib-figures-not-showing-up-or-displaying/) are:

```
$ workon plotting
$ pip uninstall matplotlib
$ git clone https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib.git
$ cd matplotlib
$ python setup.py install
```

Changing backends and using --system-site-packages didn't work for me.