# ImportError: Gtk* backend requires pygtk to be installed. Python 3.4 - No solution seems to work

Tags: python, python-3.x, ubuntu, matplotlib

I am learning how to use MATPLOTLIB and I am following some examples form the book "Matplotlib for Python Developers".
.
In one of the examples, the author uses the following code:

```
import matplotlib as mpl
mpl.use('GTKAgg')
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

The problem is, when I try to run this code, I get the following error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_gtk.py", line 15, in 
>       import gobject
>   ImportError: No module named 'gobject'
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "", line 1, in
>   
>       from matplotlib import pyplot as plt   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/matplotlib/pyplot.py", line
>   114, in 
>       _backend_mod, new_figure_manager, draw_if_interactive, _show = pylab_setup()   File
>   "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/matplotlib/backends/**init**.py",
>   line 32, in pylab_setup
>       globals(),locals(),[backend_name],0)   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_gtkagg.py",
>   line 14, in 
>       from matplotlib.backends.backend_gtk import gtk, FigureManagerGTK, FigureCanvasGTK,\   File
>   "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_gtk.py",
>   line 19, in 
>       raise ImportError("Gtk* backend requires pygtk to be installed.") ImportError: Gtk* backend requires pygtk to be installed.

I've found a "solution" [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22304215/gtk-backend-requires-pygtk-to-be-installed), but since I am very new to this, I have no idea of what I must do.

Can someone here give me any idea of what exactly I have to do?

Thank you all in advance,

Comment: Did you try `pip install pygtk`?

Comment: Yes, I did. I used synaptic package manager to verify if PYGTK is installed, and it is ok.

Comment: If you are using a virtualenv like in the linked solution, try installing it in the virtualenv. It is possible that `pygtk` is not finding the version installed with your OS's package manager.

Comment: But I am not using virtualenv.

Comment: It is generally recommended to use a virtualenv. See: http://stackoverflow.com/a/40675615/1513933

Comment: Ok... But right now, in this case, I am not using it.

Comment: Did you tryed the answers to this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22304215/gtk-backend-requires-pygtk-to-be-installed?noredirect=1&lq=1 ?

Answer (score 0):

On Windows I use Anaconda, which makes installing [PyGObject](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GObject) and GTK easy:

```
conda install -c conda-forge pygobject
conda install -c conda-forge gtk3
```

Then you can use `GTK3Agg`:

```
import matplotlib as mpl
mpl.use('GTK3Agg')

# Check if it worked
assert(mpl.get_backend() == 'GTK3Agg')
```

...although I found it wasn't actually any faster for my use case than `TKAgg`, anyway, and it still had [weird warnings](https://github.com/bottlesdevs/Bottles/issues/590).  So I stopped using it.  (i.e. I deleted the line `mpl.use('GTK3Agg')`)