# Amazon EMR cluster matplotlib error

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, matplotlib, emr, apache-zeppelin

I'm using an AWS cluster EMR 5.3.1 with Hadoop + Spark + Hive + Zeppelin

When I use Zeppelin and type command:

```
%python
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.plot([1, 2, 3])
```

I get error:

```
ImportError: Gtk3 backend requires pygobject to be installed.
```

How to solve it?

Answer (score 6):

Before importing `pyplot` module you need to change matplotlib's backend to `Agg`

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('Agg')
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.plot([1,2,3])
```